# Attaching VM Scale Set to Application Gateway's backend pool

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Can anyone provide an example of how to add an Azure VM Scale Set (VMSS) to an application  gateway's backend pool using Terraform.

I can only find [one example](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/1501#issuecomment-414052781) that I cannot get to work for me. Although `terraform plan` and `terraform apply` do not error, the VMSS is not added to the backend pool. I wonder if my problems are caused by the fact the `backend_address_pool` output from the app gateway resource is a block as opposed to a single attribute.

I am using Terraform 0.12.5, with AzureRM provider 1.31.0.

#### App Gateway resource output:

```
output "name" {
  value = azurerm_application_gateway.pool[*].name
}

output "id" {
  value = azurerm_application_gateway.pool[*].id
}

output "backend_address_pool" {
  value = azurerm_application_gateway.pool[*].backend_address_pool
}
```

#### VMSS module declaration:

```
module "vmss_example" {
...
application_gateway_backend_address_pool_ids = ["${module.app_gateway_example[0].id}/backendAddressPools/my-backend-address-pool"]
}
```

---

After the resources have been created, rerunning `terraform plan` wants to change the vmss from:

```
...
- ip_configuration {
              - application_gateway_backend_address_pool_ids = [] -> null
              - application_security_group_ids               = [] -> null
              - load_balancer_backend_address_pool_ids       = [] -> null
              - load_balancer_inbound_nat_rules_ids          = [] -> null
              - name                                         = "ipconfig" -> null
              - primary                                      = true -> null
              - subnet_id                                    = "/subscriptions/#########-####-####-####-############/resourceGroups/demo-modules-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnetdemodemo01/subnets/subnetdemovm01" -> null
            }
...
```

to:

```
...
+ ip_configuration {
              + application_gateway_backend_address_pool_ids = (known after apply)
              + application_security_group_ids               = []
              + load_balancer_backend_address_pool_ids       = []
              + load_balancer_inbound_nat_rules_ids          = (known after apply)
              + name                                         = "ipconfig"
              + primary                                      = true
              + subnet_id                                    = "/subscriptions/#########-####-####-####-############/resourceGroups/demo-modules-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnetdemodemo01/subnets/subnetdemovm01"
            }
...
```

Which I believe means that it is trying to update `application_gateway_backend_address_pool_ids`.

Any help, pointers or suggestions will be gratefully received. TIA

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you just need to use `application_gateway_backend_address_pool_ids` to specify an array of references to **backend address pools** of application gateways in the [ip_configuration](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/virtual_machine_scale_set.html#application_gateway_backend_address_pool_ids) block.

For example, this works on my side with Terraform v0.12.5
+ provider.azurerm v1.32.0 :

```
ip_configuration {
  name                                   = "TestIPConfiguration"
  primary                                = true
  subnet_id                              = "${azurerm_subnet.backend.id}"
  application_gateway_backend_address_pool_ids = "${azurerm_application_gateway.network.backend_address_pool[*].id}"
}
```

Or, this also works `application_gateway_backend_address_pool_ids = ["${azurerm_application_gateway.network.backend_address_pool[0].id}"]`

Check the output

```
output "backend_address_pool" {
    value = "${azurerm_application_gateway.network.backend_address_pool[*].id}"
}
```

[image]

Comment: Nancy, is your `ip_configuration.subnet_id` a subnet for app gateway backend, VMSS or both?

Comment: It's an individual subnet for vmss. Actually, your vmss and app gw frontend should be in a different subnet but in the same vnet. I use [this example](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/application_gateway.html) to create app GW

Comment: It works in a basic tf. Thanks. I need to get it to work as a module with count. Haven't had a chance to try yet.

Comment: For using a module, take note of accessing Child Module Outputs format. outputs of child modules are available in expressions as `module.<MODULE NAME>.<OUTPUT NAME>`. https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/outputs.html#accessing-child-module-outputs

Answer (score 1):

Note that in version 3.0.0 of the `azurerm` provider the `backend_address_pool` of the `application_gateway` is now a `Set` instead of a `List`.

If you only have one `backend_address_pool` that you need to reference, you can use the [`one()` built-in function](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/one) like this:

```
ip_configuration {
  name                                   = "TestIPConfiguration"
  primary                                = true
  subnet_id                              = "${azurerm_subnet.backend.id}"
  application_gateway_backend_address_pool_ids = one(azurerm_application_gateway.network.backend_address_pool[*].id)
}
```